# Emacs LaTeX compiling : error occurs then no more error

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex

When I compile my file with Emacs with `C-c C-c`, I got this message:

```
LaTeX errors in ‘*~/path/to/myfile output*’. Use C-c ` to display.
```

Then, when I check the error with `` C-c ` ``, I get this :

```
No more errors.
```

When I compile with command line with `pdflatex`, it compiles well without errors.

Can anybody help, please ?
Thanks

Comment: Either try `M-x TeX-previous-error` or go to the output buffer and read that.  Sometime is necessary to open the `.log` file to get further details.

Comment: `M-x Tex-previous-error` does not work. Nothing interessant in the logfile.

Comment: You need to type the command name correctly with correct case.  Any genuine errors will be recorded in the `.log`; sometimes the emacs parsing just gets confused.

Comment: have you tried to compile with `C-c C-b` instead of `C-c C-c`?

Comment: @NgahyBe Welcome to TeX.SE! Apparently, you are using AUCTeX (as opposed to Emacs' built-in LaTeX mode), can you edit your question to mention it (add the `auctex` tag too)? Also, in order to help others help you, I suggest to paste, using the `{}` button when editing your question, the full contents of the buffer that shows LaTeX's output after you 1) modify and save your `.tex` file (even something insignificant) then 2) type `C-c C-c`. The buffer should be named `*path/to/your/document output*`.